# How to make 2 actions happen when a button is pressed with the TouchableHighlight component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have managed to make console output a text when the button is pressed. However, I also want each click to increase the value of a global variable called nClicks, but have struggled to do so. This is my code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
 var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
        } = React;

        var nClicks = 0;

        var simple = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Tap the button as fast as you can!
        </Text>

        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
        onPress={() =>

        nClicks++,
        console.log('pressed')}>

        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
         Tap Here!
        </Text>

        </TouchableHighlight>

  </View>
);
}
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
welcome: {
fontSize: 30,
textAlign: 'center',
                           marginTop: -280,

},
instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
},

                           button:{
                           width: 250,
                           height: 100,
                           borderColor: 'red',
                           borderWidth: 3,
                           borderRadius: 5,
                           marginTop: 60,

                           justifyContent: 'center',

                           alignItems: 'center',
                           textAlign: 'center',
                           color: 'red',

                           },

                           buttonText:{
                           fontSize: 20,
                           }



                        });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('simple', () => simple);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a constructor for the class with the counter initialization:

```
class YourClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           count: 0
       }
   }
   render() {
      //......
   }
};
```

and then when you press a TouchableHighlight component you had to increment the count variable.

```
this.setState({
    count: this.state.count + 1
})
```

This is possible because every component has a state object (and a props object too). This State is set using the setState method.